# MIPS accessing an element number that's stored in a register

Tags: mips

I've an integer stored for instance in $s1.

I have an array in $s2.

I need to find the value of the element $s1 in the array $s2.

I know the offset has to be an immediate, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale the index (`$s1`) according to the size of the array elements. This can be done with a shift, e.g. shift 2 bits to the left to scale the index for word-sized elements.

Add the scaled index to the base address (`$s2`) and load from the resulting address.